# Inserting data from qt to postgres database error

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql

In last 2-3 days I am having problem with inserting data to postgres databse from Qt program I made.

I have made connection with the database, but when I try to insert data, the program sends me this message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: EXECUTE  ('thisIsSomeName', 4, '0000')
                 ^
QPSQL: Unable to create query
```

Here is the code from Qt that insert the value.

```
QSqlQuery qsql;
qsql.prepare("INSERT INTO baza(Name, ID, Birth Date)"
                     "VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

        qsql.bindValue(0, "thisIsSomeName");
        qsql.bindValue(1, 4);
        qsql.bindValue(2, "0000");

        if (qsql.exec())
        {
            label->setText("all is good");
        }
```

Can you please tell how to make this work. Thanks.
Script of baza

```
CREATE TABLE baza
(
  "Name" name NOT NULL DEFAULT 50,
  "ID" integer NOT NULL,
  "Birth Date" text DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT baza_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE baza OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: hello,
what is the datatype of `Name` 
and can you give the full table script of baza? it will be helpful

Comment: @PresleyDias I have put the script of baza. Thank you for your help

Comment: hey drop your table and try this `CREATE TABLE baza
(
  Name name NOT NULL DEFAULT 50,
  ID integer NOT NULL,
  Birth Date text DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT baza_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE baza OWNER TO postgres;
`

Comment: that is without the `"` for `name` ,`ID` and `Birth date`

Comment: You cannot have a column with a space in it **unless** you use double quotes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : sory my bad..i have made it properly in my answer though

Answer (score 2):

try  this

```
    CREATE TABLE baza
      (
         Name  name NOT NULL DEFAULT 50,
         ID  integer NOT NULL,
         Birth_Date  text DEFAULT 0,
       CONSTRAINT baza_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
    )
     WITH (
        OIDS=FALSE
     );
       ALTER TABLE baza OWNER TO postgres;
```

then try this

```
  QSqlQuery qsql;
  qsql.prepare("INSERT INTO baza(Name, ID, Birth_Date)"
                 "VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    qsql.bindValue(0, "thisIsSomeName");
    qsql.bindValue(1, 4);
    qsql.bindValue(2, "0000");

    if (qsql.exec())
    {
        label->setText("all is good");
    }
```

here are some examples
[sql sqlstatements](http://library.maemodocs.nokia.com/fremantle/index.jsp?topic=/org.maemo.mica.maemosdk.help.api.cpp.qt46/html/sql-sqlstatements.html)

Comment: @depecheSoul: You might want to re-visit the manual regarding identifiers: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for your link I had a quick look on it And I have seen some useful stuff.